# Associative property of a product on $L_1$-functions

Tags: complex-analysis, associativity

If $f,g\in L_1$ we define the product $\Box$ as 
$$f\Box g(x)=f(x)\int_{-\infty}^xg(y)dy + g(x)\int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy $$

The first question is if this product has a special name.

So to show that it has a associative property I need to show: $[(f\Box g)\Box h](x) = [f\Box(g\Box h)](x)$. My idea was quite simple, just expand both sides and then look at what I get

$$\begin{align}[(f\Box g)\Box h](x)
&=f(x)\int_{-\infty}^xg(y)dy\int_{-\infty}^xh(y)dy + g(x)\int_{-\infty}^xf(y)dy\int_{-\infty}^xh(y)dy \\
&+ h(x)\int_{-\infty}^xf(y)dy\int_{-\infty}^yg(z)dzdy+h(x)\int_{-\infty}^xg(y)\int_{-\infty}^yf(z)dzdy
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}[f\Box(g\Box h)](x)
&= f(x)\int_{-\infty}^xg(y)\int_{-\infty}^yh(z)dzdy+f(x)\int_{-\infty}^xh(y)\int_{-\infty}^yg(z)dzdy\\
&+g(x)\int_{-\infty}^xh(y)dy\int_{-\infty}^xf(y)dy+h(x)\int_{-\infty}^xg(y)dy\int_{-\infty}^xf(y)dy
\end{align}$$

The problem is that I don't see why these two things should be the same. Hope someone can help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to change the order of intergration:

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^x dz \;  f(z) \int\limits_{-\infty}^z dy \; g(y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dy \; g(y) \int\limits_y^x dz \; f(z).
$$

Now we notice that two last terms of $(f \square g) \square h$ sum up to
$$
h(x) \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dy \; g(y) \left[ \int\limits_y^x dz \; f(z) + \int\limits_{-\infty}^y dz \; f(z) \right] = h(x) \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dy \; g(y) \right] \; \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dz \; f(z) \right].
$$

And whole expression becomes symmetric

$$
(f \square g) \square h \, (x) = 
f(x) \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dy \; g(y) \right] \; \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dz \; h(z) \right] + \\ +
g(x) \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dy \; h(y) \right] \; \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dz \; f(z) \right]+
h(x) \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dy \; g(y) \right] \; \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^x dz \; f(z) \right]
$$